# Showing that $b$ is a inner point of $\mathcal{G}$ where $\mathcal{G}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{N+3}$ determined by $\mathcal{M}^{+}$.

Tags: probability, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(\Xi,\mathscr{E})$ be a measurable space, $(\mathbb{R_{+}},\mathfrak{B})$ other measurable space where $\mathfrak{B}$ a  $\sigma$-algebra. We consider the measurable space $(\Xi\times\Xi\times\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathscr{E}\otimes\mathscr{E}\otimes \mathfrak{B})$  and $\mathcal{P}(\Xi\times\Xi\times\mathbb{R}_{+})$ the set of all probability measures in $\Xi\times\Xi\times\mathbb{R}_{+}$ and $\mathcal{M}(\Xi\times\Xi\times\mathbb{R}_{+})$ the set of all signed measures generated by $\mathcal{P}(\Xi\times\Xi\times\mathbb{R}_{+})$ and $\mathcal{M}^{+}(\Xi\times\Xi\times\mathbb{R}_{+})$ the set of all positive measures.

We assume that $\Xi  \subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and there exists a metric $d$ such that $(\Xi,d)$ is a metric space.

Let $v\geq 0$, $\left\{\widehat{\xi}_{1},\ldots, \widehat{\xi}_{N}\right\}\subseteq \Xi$ and $\varepsilon>0$. We consider the set
$$
\mathcal{G}:=\left\{\left. \left(\Pi(\Xi\times\Xi\times\mathbb{R}_{+}),\int g_{1}(\xi,\zeta,\varrho)\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta,d\varrho),\ldots,\int g_{N+2}(\xi,\zeta,\varrho)\Pi(d\xi,d\zeta,d\varrho) \right) \right| \\ \: \Pi\in \mathcal{M}^{+}(\Xi\times\Xi\times\mathbb{R}_{+}) \right\}. 
$$
where

$$g_{i}(\xi,\zeta,\varrho):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \mathbb{1}_{\left\{\zeta=\widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\}}(\xi,\zeta,\varrho) &\mbox{for }i=1,\ldots,N \\ \mathbb{1}_{\left\{\varrho=v\right\}}(\xi,\zeta,\varrho) & \mbox{for }i=N+1\\ d^{p}(\xi,\zeta)+\varrho &\mbox{for }i=N+2.  \end{array}\right.$$

**The question:** I need to show that $b=(1,1/N,\ldots,1/N,1,\varepsilon)$ is interior point of $\mathcal{G}$.

**Remark:** This problem arises when I try to understand the ideas of the article in this [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309283503_Robust_Wasserstein_Profile_Inference_and_Applications_to_Machine_Learning) (*you can download it on that web page,   it is also in arxiv but this page is not working*), specifically the proof of Proposition 4 on page 45, the author says simply that $ \mathcal{G}=\mathbb{R}^{N+3}_{+}$ but the author does not show it, for me  is important to prove it, I have tried show it so many times that I am already doubting that this fact not is true. I appreciate any help you can give me on this subject.

**Note:**  The author of the article handles a different notation where he calls $ \mathcal{G}$ as $ \mathcal{Q}_{f} $.

Comment: It looks to me like an extra condition is needed: $0<v<\epsilon.$ Maybe try asking the authors?

Comment: @Dap Actually I can prove that $0\leq v < \varepsilon$. Now, I do not know how that fact can help.

Comment: After looking again, I think it's just completely wrong. The vectors $b\in\mathcal G$ all satisfy $b_0\geq b_1+\dots+b_N$ and also $b_0\geq b_{N+1},$ but that particular $b$ makes both these inequalities sharp so it can't be an interior point. (We can just add some mass that increases $b_0$ but not $b_1,\dots,b_{N+1},$ so it's not even in the relative interior.)